# CSS Grid layout: specify grid position with less typing?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

(I am trying to convert this data entry page from a very primitive CSS/HTML "table" layout to something a bit better, using CSS Grid layout).

In line with common practice, it seems, I've made it 12 columns wide. Each entry field has a label, of the same width. In other words my CSS is currently very repetitive:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

#SigNameLabel {
  grid-column: 1 / 13;
  grid-row: 2;
}

#SignatureName {
  grid-column: 5 / 13;
  grid-row: 2;
}

#PaymentNoLabel {
  grid-column: 1 / 13;
  grid-row: 3;
}

#PaymentNo {
  grid-column: 5 / 13;
  grid-row: 3;
}

#CurrencyLabel {
  grid-column: 1 / 13;
  grid-row: 4;
}

#Currency {
  grid-column: 5 / 13;
  grid-row: 4;
}

* {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id='SigNameLabel' class='unselectable'>Signature name:</div>
  <div id='SignatureName' class='unselectable dataField single-line'></div>

  <div id='PaymentNoLabel' class='unselectable'>Payment No:</div>
  <div id='PaymentNo' class='unselectable dataField single-line'></div>

  <div id='CurrencyLabel' class='unselectable'>Currency:</div>
  <div id='Currency' class='dataField single-line'></div>
</div>
```

Short of using JS to "create" the layout in automated fashion, i.e. by analysing the `DIVs` in the `container`, is there any way to make the CSS less cumbersome and explicit, more just "taking its lead from" what the HTML does?

For example, I have had to give a specific ID to each of the labels here: when they each sat in their own `TD` they didn't need that. Is there any way each such label `DIV` could be given a class, say `left-hand-column`, and somehow they could all have `grid-column: 1 /  13` applied to them, and somehow the same `grid-row` as the data field `DIV` to their right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code like below. And you don't necessarily need 12 columns

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.container>*:nth-child(even) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  border:1px solid;
}
.container>*:nth-child(odd) {
  /* Not sure if you need this but it will allow 
     the full width of the grid like your code grid-column: 1 / 13;
  width:calc(300% + 2*10px); */
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id='SigNameLabel' class='unselectable'>Signature name:</div>
  <div id='SignatureName' class='unselectable dataField single-line'></div>

  <div id='PaymentNoLabel' class='unselectable'>Payment No:</div>
  <div id='PaymentNo' class='unselectable dataField single-line'></div>

  <div id='CurrencyLabel' class='unselectable'>Currency:</div>
  <div id='Currency' class='dataField single-line'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks... just what I was looking for. Tiny niggle: when I run the code snippet "Signature name:" spills over into the right-hand box. Is there any way to ensure that word-wrapping occurs instead of overspill?

Comment: @mikerodent simply remove the style where I added the comment `width:300%...` .. In your initial code you were using `grid-column:1/13` which is also creating the same effect, that's why I was not sure